# Add filter to Curl Command for API

Tags: curl, filter, postman

When I use Postman to get data from the API. I am able to successfully filter it.

```
https://xx.com/admin/v1/Users 
https://xx/admin/v1/Users?filter=userName co "random.user"
```

However, when I try using CURL , I am stuck at the URL. The Curl comand provided by the API provider is

```
curl -k -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $AccessToken" "https://xx/admin/v1/Users" -o search_results.json
```

How do I add filter to the command above ?

Comment: Why not use the code feature to get the same curl command you're using in Postman...that works :D https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTtS4-r2oSs

Comment: :D that works. Thanks for taking out the time :)